# Why is SetPixel so slow and are there any alternatives to it?

Tags: c++, drawing, lag

I've gotten up to the part where lots of drawing is going on, but the more objects I add to draw, the laggier my program gets. Such as simple squares or rectangles, objects simultaneously 1 - 256.

I've googled some and most suggest including a graphics library, but what if I wanted to create my own graphcis library?

Any help / examples appreciated.

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
```

Comment: Double-buffering? "Draw" on an in-memory bitmap, blit it into the on-display bitmap.

Comment: You likely have over 2 million pixels on your screen. Making an OS call and forcing a context switch every time you want to set one is removing yourself far from the actual drawing. Even something as basic as GDI comes with functions to draw shapes in one go.

Answer (score 1):

`SetPixel` is a GDI function. Games typically use DirectX, which is quite a bit faster. Modern GPU's work best if you can express your drawing in terms of triangles and textures.

Comment: Well I'm on a laptop, with MX250.